# Transferring large size files from openshift container to different server

Tags: kubernetes, unix, openshift, tar, rsync

I have a scenario, where we are transferring multiple files from openshift to a different server. It's in Terabytes.

Right now using oc client. Tried few options.

```
oc cp podname:source_path target_path

oc rsync --exclude="*.txt",".log" podname:source_path target_path
```

It's running for hours.

Any other better approach to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what kind of data you have to save and how your application writes, but it could still be a good idea to use Object Storage (which is reachable via the Internet) and give the right Grants.

https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/openshift-applications-using-object-storage

This way you will have a single point where you save the data and you will no longer have to worry about moving it externally.

If you want to stay entirely on RedHat, you can release Ceph in your cluster, otherwise you can rely on a Cloud provider.

Comment: It's csv files.